# MySQL / MariaDB: CLI only supports less than 80 characters, expected or bug?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-cli

I have set up a new MariaDB Server on a server with Debian Stable
and configured a new SQL user, call it 'user', with the password '123456' (EDIT: I used a generated password with exact 80 characters).
I can now use `mysql -uuser -p123456` on the machine to login to this user.
Also using a local phpMyAdmin instance is working fine.

However a node application written by myself cannot log in on this server,
on other machines with similiar configurations the application can.

After lot of debugging I discovered that I cannot login via the mysql-cli too if I am not input the password via the arguments. Example:

```
$ mysql -uuser -p
Enter password: [type in 123456]
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I cannot imagine why some login methods work and others don't,
and on each machine before,
I experienced no difference between `mysql [...] -p [ENTER] password` and `mysql [...] -ppassword`.

The logfile of the MariaDB server reflects all successful and non-successful authentications.

Can someone maybe explain what is may be misconfigured on this server?

EDIT:

First, I accidentally misconfigured my node application, after fixing the app can now login successfully.

Also, I retried using a shorter password, then everything worked fine. After more attempts, I think the MySQL Cli (at least on Debian) only supports passwords containing less than 80 characters (79 characters are working fine). Does someone know if this is expected or not?

Comment: How wide is your 'Terminal'?  What happens if you change the width?

Comment: 239x58 or 159x57, depends on which monitor I use, so it should be wide enough

Comment: Tested it inside a docker container on a clean Debian Stable, no difference when using different terminal sizes (below 50 characters too)